# Con statement outputs using arcpy.sa.Con doesn't ignore NoData

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, nodata, con

In ArcGIS 10.2, using the Con tool, I ran a conditional statement to return RasterA where RasterB value >0. That worked fine. Transferring the code into python, the statement reads something like:

```
arcpy.gp.Con_sa()
```

BUT, I don't want to write the output to disk yet, so I'm going to use:

```
outraster = arcpy.sa.Con()
```

To see if the output is right, I save this to disk:

```
ouraster.save(output location)
```

The resulting output does not ignore NoData, it repalces it with value 0. arcpy.gp.Con_sa() successfully ignores NoData values and transfers them to the output raster as NoData. arcpy.sa.Con() fills all the NoData values with 0 in the output. This increases processing time and is unnecessary.

Any idea why this is happening?